# extract columns according to a list

Tags: r, nlp

I have a table df, which lists the frequency of 2000 words in 1000 document

```
id   happy so  today    cut  song dad  may
 1    2      4     3     2    1    0    2 
 2    1      2     1     4    0    2    2
 3    0      2     1     1    2    0    3
```

I want to extract some columns (words) from the table according to a list like this:

```
     Topic 1   Topic 2   
[1,] "cut"     "one"     
[2,] "may"     "day"     
[3,] "song"    "job"     
[4,] "act"     "start"   
[5,] "control" "check"
```

extracting one column from a table is df$col, here the column names in df are the names in the list. The outcome would be like this:

```
id    cut  may song 
 1     2     2   1    
 2     4     2   0
 3     1     3   2
```

Comment: Do you have a typo in the expected output i.e. the 3rd element of `may` would be 3, right?

Comment: `df[,words$Topic1[words$Topic1 %in% names(df)]]`, or `lapply`/`sapply` across the columns of `words`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match`.  To extract the columns in "df1" based on the first column of "m2"

```
df1[c(1, match(m2[,"Topic1"], names(df1), nomatch=0))]
#   id cut may song
#1  1   2   2    1
#2  2   4   2    0
#3  3   1   3    2
```

As 'm2' is `matrix`, we can also do this for all the columns in the same step

```
df1[c(1, match(m2, names(df1), nomatch=0))]
```

If we need to subset the initial dataset based on each of the columns in "m2" (`matrix`),

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(m2)), function(i) 
        df1[c(1, match(m2[,i], names(df1), nomatch=0))]
        )
#[[1]]
#  id cut may song
#1  1   2   2    1
#2  2   4   2    0
#3  3   1   3    2

#[[2]]
#  id
#1  1
#2  2
#3  3
```

NOTE: In the second column of "m2", there is no element that matches with the column names of 'df1'.